# Resize Fabric Rect without resizing Textbox

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/o8f7Lne0/21/) I have a Fabric group containing a Rect and a Textbox. I need to be able to scale the Rect without scaling the text, so I'm trying to ungroup when the group is selected, and group again when the selection is cleared. Also:

- The Rect and the Textbox are grouped to be able to move them together.
- The text needs to be editable.
- The text needs to be on top of the rect (i.e. should be always visible).

How to make the jsFiddle work?

**NOTE**

The text and the rectangle always move together, even before or after any selection.

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.Textbox("Some text", {
     width: 100,
     height: 22,
     fontSize: 12,
     editable: true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
     width: 100,
     height: 22,
     fill: 'yellow'
});

var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
  left: 30,
  top: 30
});

canvas.add(group);

group.on('selected', function (e){
   canvas.remove(group);
   canvas.add(rect);
   canvas.add(text);
   canvas.renderAll();
   canvas.setActiveObject(rect);

});

canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(e) {
    group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {});
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**: the OP clarified some of the requirements, so the solution was edited accordingly.

While grouping may seem like a good idea at first, if you think about it, the only group feature your text/rect combination needs is the ability to move together. Which means that creating a group and trying to disable all the unwanted features is actually harder than glueing Text to your Rect and only handling events that you care about.

Fabric.js has a wonderful [subclassing](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#subclassing) mechanism, which we'll use to extend `fabric.Rect` class.

The code below is pretty much self-explanatory, I'll just note several key aspects:

- `rectOptions` and `textOptions` passed into the `fabric.RectWithText` constructor, are the objects you would normally pass into `fabric.Rect` and `fabric.Textbox` constructors, accordingly.
- the `Textbox` is referenced by a `text` property of the `RectWithText` instance.
- `recalcTextPosition` uses a couple of trigonometry formulas to calculate text's position in relation to the rectangle, given the initial offset between the two.
- we need to keep an eye on the rectangle's `moving`, `scaling`, and `rotating` events to recalculate text's position smoothly.
- `mousedown:before`, `mousedblclick`, `editing:exited` make sure the text stays editable on double click.
- we're keeping the text on top by modifying `canvas.preserveObjectStacking` when the object is clicked on.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

fabric.RectWithText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: 'rectWithText',
    text: null,
    textOffsetLeft: 0,
    textOffsetTop: 0,
    _prevObjectStacking: null,
    _prevAngle: 0,
  
    recalcTextPosition: function () {
      const sin = Math.sin(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
      const cos = Math.cos(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
      const newTop = sin * this.textOffsetLeft + cos * this.textOffsetTop
      const newLeft = cos * this.textOffsetLeft - sin * this.textOffsetTop
      const rectLeftTop = this.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
      this.text.set('left', rectLeftTop.x + newLeft)
      this.text.set('top', rectLeftTop.y + newTop)
    },
    
    initialize: function (rectOptions, textOptions, text) {
      this.callSuper('initialize', rectOptions)
      this.text = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
        ...textOptions,
        selectable: false,
        evented: false,
      })
      this.textOffsetLeft = this.text.left - this.left
      this.textOffsetTop = this.text.top - this.top
      this.on('moving', () => {
        this.recalcTextPosition()
      })
      this.on('rotating', () => {
        this.text.rotate(this.text.angle + this.angle - this._prevAngle)
        this.recalcTextPosition()
        this._prevAngle = this.angle
      })
      this.on('scaling', (e) => {
        this.recalcTextPosition()
      })
      this.on('added', () => {
        this.canvas.add(this.text)
      })
      this.on('removed', () => {
        this.canvas.remove(this.text)
      })
      this.on('mousedown:before', () => {
        this._prevObjectStacking = this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking
        this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true
      })
      this.on('mousedblclick', () => {
        this.text.selectable = true
        this.text.evented = true
        this.canvas.setActiveObject(this.text)
        this.text.enterEditing()
        this.selectable = false
      })
      this.on('deselected', () => {
        this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = this._prevObjectStacking
      })
      this.text.on('editing:exited', () => {
        this.text.selectable = false
        this.text.evented = false
        this.selectable = true
      })
    }
})

const rectOptions = {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 75,
  fill: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3)',
}
const textOptions = {
  left: 35,
  top: 30,
  width: 150,
  fill: 'white',
  shadow: new fabric.Shadow({
    color: 'rgba(34, 34, 100, 0.4)',
    blur: 2,
    offsetX: -2,
    offsetY: 2
  }),
  fontSize: 30,
}
const rectWithText = new fabric.RectWithText(rectOptions, textOptions, 'Some text')
canvas.add(rectWithText)
```

```css
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found a little defect: if while selecting/editing the text you move the rectangle, the text doesn't move

Comment: @ps0604 Isn't the idea to be able to move the rectangle freely after clicking on any part of the group?

Comment: No, the text and the rectangle always move together, even after/while you edit the text.

Comment: @ps0604 Well, suppose you've just destroyed the group and set `rect` as an active object to be able to scale it independently of `text`. Do you mean that `text` is supposed to move together with `rect` _before_ selection removal in such case?

Comment: yes, the `text` and the `rect` always move together, before or after any selection. By the way, the `text` doesn't need to be selectable, only editable.

Comment: @ps0604 Ok, this requirement makes it quite a bit more complicated. I'd suggest you add this 'always move together' rule to your post for future readers. Also, at this point, I'm not quite sure you need groups, maybe subclassing is a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I added the note to the question

Comment: for some reason I don't see the link to the chat, can you ask the question here?

Comment: @ps0604 If the text is not selectable, you won't be able to move/resize it once you've added it to the group. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, the text shouldn't be resized, only the group/rect is resized while the text keeps its original size. Similarly, the text is not moved, only the group/rect is moved with the text inside.

Comment: we need to recalc position of text at center of box vertically and horizontally , Can you Please help me to do this ? This is my question with demo snippet : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058890/how-to-make-custom-class-in-fabric-js-using-fabric-textbox-class-override

Comment: How This Custom klass Can Be loadFromJson ? Can you Please update code for that ?

Comment: I think this implemention can not handle the situation that I invoke `rectWithText.set('left', someValue)`

Comment: @shkaper excellent solution. if I may ask for further help, how would you go about to center the text both horizontally and vertically?