# fabricjs how to double-click a picture(or rect) to edit text and name it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, text, fabricjs

How to combine images and text with fabricjs and edit text when double clicking the combined object,
Still combine after editing text,
Please tell me how to edit text when rendering image and text combinations

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

// a rect
const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fill: "#ccc",
  left: 170,
  top: 80,
  width: 50,
  height: 50
});

// a text for describe rect
const text = new fabric.IText("describe rect", {
  fontFamily: "Comic Sans",
  fontSize: 14,
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fill: "#000",
  left: 170,
  top: 80
});

// 1 Combine the above two things but can not edit text

// 2 use LabeledRect also
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you can

1. Create a subclass of Image class (or whatever object that you need to attach a label to)
2. Make it create an instance of IText or Textbox and save an internal reference to it
3. By hooking into the event handlers on the image (e.g. double click), manually manage the events of the text. Make sure to keep the position and dimensions of the text updated when the image is modified.

Take a look at this answer: [Resize Fabric Rect without resizing Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633710/resize-fabric-rect-without-resizing-textbox/57649653#57649653). It does something very similar to what you've described.